# Django : ManyToManyField is missing from table

Tags: django

i have following two models :
**models.py**

```
class Genre(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Movies(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=False) 
    plot =  models.CharField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    actors = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True)
    director = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True) 
    genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genre)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

**forms.py**

```
class MovieForm(forms.ModelForm):
    genre = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Movies
```

when i run syncdb `movies , genre , movies_genre` tables are created

```
movies_genre table has (id, movies_id , genre_id)
```

However in **movies** table , no cloumn is created for genre field, which should like **genre_id**

why genre_id field is missing from movies table?

EDIT :.................how i am adding data:

```
def genre_save(request):
   genre_name = request.POST['genre']
   genre_obj = Genre(name=genre_name)
   genre_obj.save() 
   movie_obj = Movies(genre=genre_obj.id)
   movie_obj.save() // error
```

**TypeError 'genre' is an invalid keyword argument for this function**

```
def add_movie(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
     genre_save(request)
     form_post = MovieForm(request.POST)
     form_post.save()
     /// other stuff....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed earlier Django creates a separate table for many to many field. Also what is the point of this `def genre_save(request)` function ? Why can't you simply do it in your view?

Anyways you could try the following:

```
def genre_save(request):
    genre_name = request.POST['genre']
    genre_obj = Genre(name=genre_name)
    genre_obj.save() 
    movie_obj = Movies(name="My Movie")
    movie_obj.save()
    # this is how you should do it
    movie_obj.genre.add(genre_obj)
    # OR like this
    movie_obj.genre = [genre_obj]
    movie_obj.save()
```

Read here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Answer (score 3):

Django creates a separate table for many to many field,with references to both the tables.The new table will have `foreign key` to both the tables,`movies` and `genre`. So you wont see a new column,but you will surely find a new table.

So whenever you add `genre` for the `movie`, a new row is created for every `genre` you add in the `movies_genre` table.

For example for a movie `a` with movie `id` 1, you add genre b,c with genre `id`s 1,2, the following are created in the `movie_genre` table

```
id     movie_id   genre_id
1        1           1 
2        1           2
```

Comment: when i am adding the movie although the movies and genre table has been populated, movie_genre table is not being populated

Comment: Did u add the genre to the movie?

Comment: genre is not field in movies table then how can i add ?

Comment: how are you adding the data?try using django admin